# Passing unmanaged template class instance as parameter in different dll fails compilation

Tags: c++, templates, interop, c++-cli

I have unmanaged, template class for thread safe queue:

```
    template<class T>
    public class TSQueue {...}
```

And Producer class:

```
    public ref class Producer
    {
        Producer(TSQueue<int>* Q) {...}
    };
```

Producer is used in following way:

```
    Producer^ p = gcnew Producer(new TSQueue<int>());
```

Both are defined in one C++/CLI DLL Producer.DLL.

When **Producer** is instantiated and provided with **TSQueue< int >*** inside this DLL, there are no problems with compilation and execution.

But, when I try to instantiate **Producer** with **TSQueue< int >*** in another, C++/CLI dll I am having the following compiler error:

```
    Error   23  error C2664: 'Producer(TSQueue<int>*)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TSQueue<T> *' to 'TSQueue<int> *'
```

As if compiler cannot determine the type of Q I provide to Producer constructor.

I have added reference to Producer.DLL.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Fairly sure you have a type identity problem here, induced by having a native C++ template cross a module boundary.  That's in general a notorious problem in C++, templates don't have external linkage.  It is easy to solve in C++/CLI by using generics, you should have a drop-in replacement for TSQueue from the .NET Queue<> class, ConcurrentQueue<> if it needs to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i was not familiar with this constraint. The thing is that I need template container for unmanaged types, and this is why I cannot user generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant sad:

> Fairly sure you have a type identity problem here, induced by having a native C++ template cross a module boundary. That's in general a notorious problem in C++, templates don't have external linkage. It is easy to solve in C++/CLI by using generics, you should have a drop-in replacement for TSQueue from the .NET Queue<> class, ConcurrentQueue<> if it needs to be thread-safe.

But the generics cannot be used for unmanaged types, so I am using type specific unmanaged container class.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, adding reference to the DLL isn't enough since we are dealing here w/ "native" templates and not w/ generics.
Please make sure that your *other* DLL has a `#include` directive to the header of `TSQueue`

Comment: ..and the header must have the source code of `TSQueue` template included to work. Just the header for a template won't be enough I think.

Comment: I have not mentioned, but I have included header with definition and implementation of template class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the complete definition of TSQueue in both libraries. Don't make it part of the interface use it only internally. If it needs to be a part of the API, follow the advice from Hans Passant: make it a generic, or better, use the proper framework implementation.